# node js: как подключиться к БД elastic search, запущенной на удаленном ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

1. установил Java по [инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-22-04#installing-the-default-jrejdk)
2. установил Elasticsearch на удаленный сервер Ubuntu 22.04 64bit (4 ГБ RAM, 60 ГБ SSD, 2 CPU) по [инструкции](https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-elk-stack/#Ubuntu_Debian). Пока не стал устанавливать: Kibana, Logstash, Filebeat, Winlogbeat.
3. проверил работу Elasticsearch с помощью команды: `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`
   [image: скриншот]

**Вопрос №1: как подключиться к серверу, на котором запущен Elasticsearch?**

нашел несколько вариантов:

```js
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')

const client = new Client({
  node: 'http://<IP_adress>:9200',
  auth: { apiKey: 'base64EncodedKey' }, // где его взять то?
})

const client2 = new Client({
  cloud: { id: '<cloud-id>' }, // где его взять то?
  auth: { apiKey: 'base64EncodedKey' }, // где его взять то?
})

const client3 = new Client({
  cloud: { id: '<cloud-id>' }, // где его взять то?
  auth: {
    username: 'username', // как узнать?
    password: 'password', // уже имеется
  },
})

const client4 = new Client({
  node: 'http://<IP_adress>:9200',
  auth: {
    username: 'username', // как узнать?
    password: 'password', // уже имеется
  },
})
```

я пошел по пути №4 (client4):

```js
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')

const client = new Client({
  node: 'http://<IP_adress>:9200',
  auth: {
    username: 'username', // как узнать?
    password: '<pswd>', // имеется
  },
})

async function run() {
  const response = await client.info()
  console.log(response)
}

run().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

в результате получаю ошибку подключения к БД на строчке кода `const response = await client.info()`
[image: скриншот]

PS: как я получил пароль к elastic search:

1. для создания паролей использовал команду:
   `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto`
2. получил в ответ ошибку:
   Unexpected response code [500] from calling GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty
   It doesn't look like the X-Pack security feature is enabled on this Elasticsearch node.
   Please check if you have enabled X-Pack security in your elasticsearch.yml configuration file.
   ERROR: X-Pack Security is disabled by configuration.
3. тогда прописал в файле `elasticsearch.yml` в секции `Security`: `xpack.security.enabled: true`
4. перезапустил Elasticsearch командой: `systemctl restart elasticsearch.service`
5. Проверил, запустился ли он: `systemctl status elasticsearch.service`. Всё норм.
6. Решил проверить, что elasticsearch действительно нормально работает. Выполнил к нему простой запрос о его статусе: `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`
7. получил ответ:
   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""}},"status":401}
8. после этого повторил команду для создания паролей: `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto`
9. и вуаля, получил пароли для доступа

**в общем, прошу помочь разобраться как подключиться к elastic search, запущенной на удаленном Ubuntu**

**Вопрос №2: какие еще необходимо сделать минимальные настройки БД?**

**Вопрос №3: подскажите плиз, где найти полную инструкцию по настройке Elastic search?**

на [одном форуме](https://russianblogs.com/article/71611293508/) нашел рекомендации по настройке кластера, но еще не делал этого.
Например: `cluster.name: my-community`

**Вопрос №4: как автоматически увеличивать document id, чтобы не перезаписывать уже имеющуюся информацию?**

Answer (score 0):

доделал все шаги по [инструкции](https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-elk-stack/#Ubuntu_Debian):

1. зашел в файл настроек с помощью команды `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
2. чтобы elasticsearch слушал все сетевые интерфейсы прописал параметр: `network.host: 0.0.0.0`
3. дополнительно добавил еще один параметр `discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]`. Этим мы указываем, что хосты кластера следует искать только локально.
4. После изменения настроек перезапустил службу `systemctl restart elasticsearch.service`
5. Проверил что elasticsearch действительно нормально работает. Выполнил к нему простой запрос о его статусе `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`

ИТОГО мои настройки:

```
--- Paths ---
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

--- Network ---
network.host: 0.0.0.0

--- Discovery ---
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

кстати, нашел отличную [видео инструкцию](https://youtu.be/pi6uAncUTSs) как развернуть elasticsearch на локальном компе